# How do I search an SQL Server database for a string?

Tags: sql-server, function, search, stored-procedures

I know it's possible, but I don't know how.

I need to search an SQL Server database for all mentions of a specific string.

For example: I would like to search all tables, views, functions, stored procedures, ... for string "tblEmployes" (not data within the tables).

One of the reasons I need this is I would like to remove some extra data tables that are created, but I am afraid that they are maybe used somewhere in procedures or functions.

Comment: [redgate SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/)

Comment: Hope this will  help someone, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174627/searching-text-from-db-sql-server/22854200#22854200

Answer (score 203):

This will search every column of every table in a specific database. Create the stored procedure on the database that you want to search in.

*[The Ten Most Asked SQL Server Questions And Their Answers](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1#2)*:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindMyData_String
    @DataToFind NVARCHAR(4000),
    @ExactMatch BIT = 0
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Temp TABLE(RowId INT IDENTITY(1,1), SchemaName sysname, TableName sysname, ColumnName SysName, DataType VARCHAR(100), DataFound BIT)

    INSERT  INTO @Temp(TableName,SchemaName, ColumnName, DataType)
    SELECT  C.Table_Name,C.TABLE_SCHEMA, C.Column_Name, C.Data_Type
    FROM    Information_Schema.Columns AS C
            INNER Join Information_Schema.Tables AS T
                ON C.Table_Name = T.Table_Name
        AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
    WHERE   Table_Type = 'Base Table'
            And Data_Type In ('ntext','text','nvarchar','nchar','varchar','char')


DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @MAX INT
DECLARE @TableName sysname
DECLARE @ColumnName sysname
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @PARAMETERS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @DataExists BIT
DECLARE @SQLTemplate NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT  @SQLTemplate = CASE WHEN @ExactMatch = 1
                            THEN 'If Exists(Select *
                                          From   ReplaceTableName
                                          Where  Convert(nVarChar(4000), [ReplaceColumnName])
                                                       = ''' + @DataToFind + '''
                                          )
                                     Set @DataExists = 1
                                 Else
                                     Set @DataExists = 0'
                            ELSE 'If Exists(Select *
                                          From   ReplaceTableName
                                          Where  Convert(nVarChar(4000), [ReplaceColumnName])
                                                       Like ''%' + @DataToFind + '%''
                                          )
                                     Set @DataExists = 1
                                 Else
                                     Set @DataExists = 0'
                            END,
        @PARAMETERS = '@DataExists Bit OUTPUT',
        @i = 1

SELECT @i = 1, @MAX = MAX(RowId)
FROM   @Temp

WHILE @i <= @MAX
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @SQL = REPLACE(REPLACE(@SQLTemplate, 'ReplaceTableName', QUOTENAME(SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TableName)), 'ReplaceColumnName', ColumnName)
        FROM    @Temp
        WHERE   RowId = @i


        PRINT @SQL
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, @PARAMETERS, @DataExists = @DataExists OUTPUT

        IF @DataExists =1
            UPDATE @Temp SET DataFound = 1 WHERE RowId = @i

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

SELECT  SchemaName,TableName, ColumnName
FROM    @Temp
WHERE   DataFound = 1
GO
```

To run it, just do this:

```
exec FindMyData_string 'google', 0
```

It works amazingly well!!!

Comment: what does the 2nd param "exactMatch = 0" means ?

Comment: If you look at the script it is just a param that is checked in a case statement early on to decide whether to string search using 'value' or '%value%'

Comment: This only returns the first result it finds and nothing else. Is there a way for it to return all instances of the string in the database?

Comment: Where do i have to save this script and what extension does the file need to be executed? Where do i execute `exec FindMyData_string 'google', 0` ?

Comment: Some databases are not case sensitive please use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS on your code. Otherwise this script will throw 'invalid object name Information_Schema' error.

Comment: I tried to edit this to work with case sensitive collations, but something went wrong and it tells me the "edit queue is full".

Comment: I need to find an INT, is this possible with this?

Comment: The link is broken nowadays...

Answer (score 62):

If you need to find database objects (e.g. tables, columns, and triggers) by name - have a look at the **free** Redgate Software tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **free** to use for any kind of use??

Comment: Good tool, but it doesn't search for strings in tables

Comment: Does not search the actual rows

Comment: @LearningJrDev: **no** - it searches the **database objects** - the tables, views, stored procedures etc. - by name. It does **NOT** search in the data contained in the tables - I never claimed it did!

Comment: @JGilmartin Let me quote part of the question _I would like to search all tables, views, functions, stored procedures, ... for string "tblEmployes". **(Not data within the tables)**_
If you want to search data within the table you have T-SQL language.
This tool is great for refactoring tasks.

Answer (score 51):

You can also try [ApexSQL Search](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx) – it’s a free [SSMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) add-in similar to [SQL Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redgate#History).

If you really want to use only SQL you might want to try this script:

```
select
S.name as [Schema],
o.name as [Object],
o.type_desc as [Object_Type],
C.text as [Object_Definition]
from sys.all_objects O inner join sys.schemas S on O.schema_id = S.schema_id
inner join sys.syscomments C on O.object_id = C.id
where S.schema_id not in (3,4) -- avoid searching in sys and INFORMATION_SCHEMA schemas
and C.text like '%ICE_%'
order by [Schema]
```

Comment: This query only search for objects. We need to search a string in all existing tables.

Comment: ApexSQL though does a great job of letting you choose your types

Comment: It is not free anymore :(

Answer (score 30):

You can export your database (if small) to your hard drive / desktop, and then just do a string search via a text search program or text editor.

Comment: :) You could use a script too. But a good text editor could do almost anything you would need for an SQL code.

Comment: And which text editor would be happy to load many GBs of data?

Comment: Probably none, but in that case you can use a third party file search engine, and there are applications that can split the file into as many as pieces you'd like.

Comment: MS SQL exports are binary files and therefore cannot be exported, read or searched using the method you proposed.

Comment: Is this even possible? I do this in many other systems (one file per table, one line per row, and then just use `grep`... but in MSSQL it doesn't seem to exist any "dump" as SQL at all...
**edit** I forgot, I mean on MacOS... Azure doesn't support it, and SQL Server Management Studio is not available.

Comment: @estani is this something that can work for you? https://www.howtogeek.com/50295/backup-your-sql-server-database-from-the-command-line/ - using sqlcmd to dump database in SQL - but unfortunately Spencer says MSSQL dump files are binary

Answer (score 16):

For getting a table by name in SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
WHERE name LIKE '%Employees%'
```

For finding a stored procedure by name:

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.objects
WHERE name = 'spName'
```

To get all stored procedures related to a table:

```
----Option 1
SELECT DISTINCT so.name
FROM syscomments sc
INNER JOIN sysobjects so ON sc.id=so.id
WHERE sc.TEXT LIKE '%tablename%'
----Option 2
SELECT DISTINCT o.name, o.xtype
FROM syscomments c
INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON c.id=o.id
WHERE c.TEXT LIKE '%tablename%'
```

Comment: This queries only search for objects. We need to search a string in all existing tables.

Answer (score 12):

This code searching procedure and function but *not search in table* :)

```
SELECT name 
FROM   sys.all_objects 
WHERE  Object_definition(object_id) 
LIKE '%text%' 
ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 5):

The content of all stored procedures, views and functions are stored in field **text** of table **sysComments**. The name of all objects are stored in table **sysObjects** and the columns are in **sysColumns**.

Having this information, you can use this code to search in content of views, stored procedures, and functions for the specified word:

```
Select b.name from syscomments a
inner join sysobjects b on a.id = b.id
where text like '%tblEmployes%'
```

This query will give you the objects which contains the word "tblEmployes" .

To search by the name of Objects you can use this code:

```
Select name from sysobjects
where name like  '%tblEmployes%'
```

And finally to find the objects having at least one column containing the word "tblEmployes", you can use this code:

```
Select b.name from syscolumns a inner join sysobjects b on a.id = b.id
where a.name like  '%tblEmployes%'
```

You can combine these three queries with union:

```
Select distinct b.name from syscomments a
inner join sysobjects b on a.id = b.id
where text like '%tblEmployes%'
union
Select distinct name from sysobjects
where name like  '%tblEmployes%'
union
Select distinct b.name from syscolumns a inner join sysobjects b on a.id = b.id
where a.name like  '%tblEmployes%'
```

With this query you have all objects containing the word "tblEmployes" in content or name or as a column.

Answer (score 4):

You could;

1. Script the database to a single file and search the file for tblEmployees using a text editor. In [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) (SSMS), right click over the database and choose *Generate Scripts*.
2. Use SSMS 'View Dependencies' by right clicking over tblEmployees to see which other objects are dependent on it
3. Use a free third-party tool such as [Redgate Software's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redgate) SQL Search to search all database objects by name and content by keyword.

Comment: #1 sounds good. I just can't run it on the server cause I don't have access rights.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why somebody gave you -1. I fixed that. Tried RedGate... that totally does what I want.

Answer (score 3):

My version...

I named it "Needle in the haystack" for obvious reasons.

It searches for a specific value in each row and each column, not for column names, etc.

Execute search (replace values for the first two variables of course):

```
DECLARE @SEARCH_DB VARCHAR(100)='REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_DB_NAME'
DECLARE @SEARCH_VALUE_LIKE NVARCHAR(100)=N'%REPLACE_WITH_SEARCH_STRING%'

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE col_cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_CATALOG=@SEARCH_DB AND DATA_TYPE NOT IN ('timestamp', 'datetime');

DECLARE @TOTAL int = (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_CATALOG=@SEARCH_DB AND DATA_TYPE NOT IN ('timestamp', 'datetime'));


DECLARE @TABLE_CATALOG nvarchar(500), @TABLE_SCHEMA nvarchar(500), @TABLE_NAME nvarchar(500), @COLUMN_NAME nvarchar(500), @DATA_TYPE nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)='';

PRINT '-------- BEGIN SEARCH --------';
OPEN col_cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM col_cur INTO @TABLE_CATALOG, @TABLE_SCHEMA, @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME, @DATA_TYPE;

BEGIN TRY DROP TABLE ##RESULTS; END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH
CREATE TABLE ##RESULTS( TABLE_CATALOG nvarchar(500), TABLE_SCHEMA nvarchar(500), TABLE_NAME nvarchar(500), COLUMN_NAME nvarchar(500), DATA_TYPE nvarchar(500), RECORDS int)
DECLARE @SHOULD_CAST bit=0
DECLARE @i int =0
DECLARE @progress_sum bigint=0

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- PRINT '' + CAST(@i as varchar(100)) +' of ' + CAST(@TOTAL as varchar(100)) + '  ' + @TABLE_CATALOG+'.'+@TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+@TABLE_NAME+': '+@COLUMN_NAME+' ('+@DATA_TYPE+')';

    SET @SHOULD_CAST = (SELECT CASE @DATA_TYPE
                                WHEN 'varchar' THEN 0
                                WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN 0
                                WHEN 'char' THEN 0
                                ELSE 1 END)

    SET @SQL='SELECT '''+@TABLE_CATALOG+''' catalog_name, '''+@TABLE_SCHEMA+''' schema_name, '''+@TABLE_NAME+''' table_name, '''+@COLUMN_NAME+''' column_name, '''+@DATA_TYPE+''' data_type, ' +
            +' COUNT(['+@COLUMN_NAME+']) records '+
            +' FROM '+@TABLE_CATALOG+'.'+@TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+@TABLE_NAME +
            +' WHERE ' + CASE WHEN @SHOULD_CAST=1 THEN 'CAST(['+@COLUMN_NAME + '] as NVARCHAR(max)) ' ELSE ' ['+@COLUMN_NAME + '] ' END
            +' LIKE '''+ @SEARCH_VALUE_LIKE + ''' '

    -- PRINT @SQL;

    IF @i % 100 = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @progress_sum = (SELECT SUM(RECORDS) FROM ##RESULTS)
            PRINT CAST (@i as varchar(100)) +' of ' + CAST(@TOTAL as varchar(100)) +': '+ CAST (@progress_sum as varchar(100))
        END

    INSERT INTO ##RESULTS (TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, RECORDS)
    EXEC(@SQL)

    FETCH NEXT FROM col_cur INTO @TABLE_CATALOG, @TABLE_SCHEMA, @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME, @DATA_TYPE;
    SET @i=@i+1
    -- IF @i > 1000
    --     BREAK
END
CLOSE col_cur;
DEALLOCATE col_cur;

SELECT * FROM ##RESULTS WHERE RECORDS>0;
```

Then to view results, even while executing, from another window, execute:

```
DECLARE @SEARCH_VALUE_LIKE NVARCHAR(100)=N'%@FLEX@%'
SELECT * FROM ##RESULTS WHERE RECORDS>0;

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE col_cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
FROM ##RESULTS WHERE RECORDS>0;

DECLARE @TABLE_CATALOG nvarchar(500), @TABLE_SCHEMA nvarchar(500), @TABLE_NAME nvarchar(500), @COLUMN_NAME nvarchar(500), @DATA_TYPE nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)='';

OPEN col_cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM col_cur INTO @TABLE_CATALOG, @TABLE_SCHEMA, @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME, @DATA_TYPE;
DECLARE @i int =0
DECLARE @SHOULD_CAST bit=0

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SHOULD_CAST = (SELECT CASE @DATA_TYPE
                                WHEN 'varchar' THEN 0
                                WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN 0
                                WHEN 'char' THEN 0
                                ELSE 1 END)

    SET @SQL='SELECT '''+@TABLE_CATALOG+''' catalog_name, '''+@TABLE_SCHEMA+''' schema_name, '''+@TABLE_NAME+''' table_name, '''+@COLUMN_NAME+''' column_name, '''+@DATA_TYPE+''' data_type, ' +
            +' ['+@COLUMN_NAME+']'+
            +', * '
            +' FROM '+@TABLE_CATALOG+'.'+@TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+@TABLE_NAME +
            +' WHERE ' + CASE WHEN @SHOULD_CAST=1 THEN 'CAST(['+@COLUMN_NAME + '] as NVARCHAR(max)) ' ELSE ' ['+@COLUMN_NAME + '] ' END
            +' LIKE '''+ @SEARCH_VALUE_LIKE + ''' '

    PRINT @SQL;

    EXEC(@SQL)

    FETCH NEXT FROM col_cur INTO @TABLE_CATALOG, @TABLE_SCHEMA, @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME, @DATA_TYPE;
    SET @i=@i+1
    -- IF @i > 10
    --    BREAK
END
CLOSE col_cur;
DEALLOCATE col_cur;
```

Few mentions about it:

- it uses cursors instead of a blocking while loop
- it can print progress (uncomment if needed)
- it can exit after a few attempts (uncomment the IF at the end)
- it displays all records
- you can fine tune it as needed

DISCLAIMERS:

- DO NOT run it in production environments!
- It is *slow*. If the DB is accessed by other services/users, *please* add " WITH (NOLOCK) " after every table name in all the selects, especially the dynamic select ones.
- It does not validate/protect against all sorts of SQL injection options.
- If your DB is huge, prepare yourself for some sleep, make sure the query will not be killed after a few minutes.
- It casts some values to string, including ints/bigints/smallints/tinyints. If you don't need those, put them at the same exclusion lists with the timestamps at the top of the script.

Answer (score 3):

I was given access to a database, but not the table where my query was being stored in.

Inspired by [@marc_s answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9188581/3357935)r, I had a look at [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) which is a Windows program that can deal with MySQL, SQL Server, and PostgreSQL.

I found that it can also search a database for a string.

[image: Click Search, then Find text on Server]

[image: Search tool open. Make sure the DB is selected]

It will search each table and give you how many times it found the string per table!

Answer (score 2):

This will search for a string over every database:

```
declare @search_term varchar(max)
set @search_term = 'something'

select @search_term = 'use ? SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
select
    ''[''+db_name()+''].[''+c.name+''].[''+b.name+'']'' as [object],
    b.type_desc as [type],
    d.obj_def.value(''.'',''varchar(max)'') as [definition]
from (
    select distinct
        a.id
    from sys.syscomments a
    where a.[text] like ''%'+@search_term+'%''
) a
inner join sys.all_objects b
    on b.[object_id] = a.id
inner join sys.schemas c
    on c.[schema_id] = b.[schema_id]
cross apply (
    select
        [text()] = a1.[text]
    from sys.syscomments a1
    where a1.id = a.id
    order by a1.colid
    for xml path(''''), type
) d(obj_def)
where c.schema_id not in (3,4) -- avoid searching in sys and INFORMATION_SCHEMA schemas
    and db_id() not in (1,2,3,4) -- avoid sys databases'

if object_id('tempdb..#textsearch') is not null drop table #textsearch
create table #textsearch
(
    [object] varchar(300),
    [type] varchar(300),
    [definition] varchar(max)
)

insert #textsearch
exec sp_MSforeachdb @search_term

select *
from #textsearch
order by [object]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I want to find where anything I want to search is, I use this:

```
DECLARE @search_string    varchar(200)
    SET @search_string = '%myString%'

    SELECT DISTINCT
           o.name AS Object_Name,
           o.type_desc,
           m.definition
      FROM sys.sql_modules m
           INNER JOIN
           sys.objects o
             ON m.object_id = o.object_id
     WHERE m.definition Like @search_string;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to search a string in your database with phpmyadmin. There you can chose from many search options and you can see where your search phrase is mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer on StackOverflow! Something that would help anyone seeking the same information would be to provide any screenshots or examples of various search options available with phpmyadmin. Thanks again for contributing!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same script as [submitted by user l--''''''---------''''''''''''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185871/how-do-i-search-an-sql-server-database-for-a-string/9185923#9185923), but corrected to work on a case-sensitive SQL instance, and with some other minor improvements.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.spFind_Text_In_Database
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spFind_Text_In_Database
    @strText_To_Find NVARCHAR(4000),
    @bitExact_Match BIT = 0
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Temp TABLE(RowId INT IDENTITY(1,1), SchemaName sysname, TableName sysname, ColumnName SysName, DataType VARCHAR(100), DataFound BIT)

    INSERT  INTO @Temp(TableName,SchemaName, ColumnName, DataType)
    SELECT  C.TABLE_NAME, C.TABLE_SCHEMA, C.COLUMN_NAME, C.DATA_TYPE
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
            INNER Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T
                ON C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
        AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
    WHERE   TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            And DATA_TYPE In ('ntext','text','nvarchar','nchar','varchar','char')


DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @MAX INT
DECLARE @TableName sysname
DECLARE @ColumnName sysname
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @PARAMETERS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @DataExists BIT
DECLARE @SQLTemplate NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT  @SQLTemplate = CASE WHEN @bitExact_Match = 1
                            THEN 'If Exists(Select *
                                          From   ReplaceTableName
                                          Where  Convert(nVarChar(4000), [ReplaceColumnName])
                                                       = ''' + @strText_To_Find + '''
                                          )
                                     Set @DataExists = 1
                                 Else
                                     Set @DataExists = 0'
                            ELSE 'If Exists(Select *
                                          From   ReplaceTableName
                                          Where  Convert(nVarChar(4000), [ReplaceColumnName])
                                                       Like ''%' + @strText_To_Find + '%''
                                          )
                                     Set @DataExists = 1
                                 Else
                                     Set @DataExists = 0'
                            END,
        @PARAMETERS = '@DataExists Bit OUTPUT',
        @i = 1

SELECT @i = 1, @MAX = MAX(RowId)
FROM   @Temp

WHILE @i <= @MAX
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @SQL = REPLACE(REPLACE(@SQLTemplate, 'ReplaceTableName', QUOTENAME(SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TableName)), 'ReplaceColumnName', ColumnName)
        FROM    @Temp
        WHERE   RowId = @i


        PRINT @SQL
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @PARAMETERS, @DataExists = @DataExists OUTPUT

        IF @DataExists =1
            UPDATE @Temp SET DataFound = 1 WHERE RowId = @i

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

SELECT  SchemaName,TableName, ColumnName
FROM    @Temp
WHERE   DataFound = 1
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching SQL Database objects is possible with [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) (SSMS) with the following methods, with SSMS Object Search: object explorer details or [T-SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) scripts as explained in following:

- [Different ways to search for SQL Server database objects](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1962/different-ways-to-search-for-sql-server-database-objects/)
- [SQL Server Find Anything in Object Explorer in SSMS](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/02/26/sql-server-find-anything-in-object-explorer-in-ssms/)
- [Search text with wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/search-text-with-wildcards?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score -2):

Here is how you can search the database in Swift using the FMDB library.

First, go to this link and add this to your project: [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). When you have done that, then here is how you do it. For example, you have a table called Person, and you have firstName and secondName and you want to find data by first name, here is a code for that:

```
    func loadDataByfirstName(firstName : String, completion: @escaping CompletionHandler){
    if isDatabaseOpened {
        let query = "select * from Person where firstName like '\(firstName)'"
        do {
            let results = try database.executeQuery(query, values: [firstName])
            while results.next() {
                let firstName = results.string(forColumn: "firstName") ?? ""
                let lastName = results.string(forColumn: "lastName") ?? ""
                let newPerson = Person(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName)
                self.persons.append(newPerson)
            }
            completion(true)
        }catch let err {
            completion(false)
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }
        database.close()
    }
}
```

Then in your ViewController you will write this to find the person detail you are looking for:

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)
      SQLManager.instance.openDatabase { (success) in
        if success {
            SQLManager.instance.loadDataByfirstName(firstName: "Hardi") { (success) in
                if success {
                    // You have your data Here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer (about SQLite) does not answer the question. The question was about [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) (Microsoft's product - though blame is also on them for choosing such a generic name for a product). From the GitHub page: *"[FMDB v2.7 ... This is an Objective-C wrapper around SQLite](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)"*