# Search a string in whole a sql server database

Tags: sql-server

I want to search a string or int in whole of my database. Such as I want to search 'Admin' in  a database. For this what can I do?

Thanks,
kibria

Comment: you can find the answer from here,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185871/how-to-search-sql-server-database-for-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this stored procedure


CREATE PROC SearchAllTables
    (
        @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN

        CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

        SET NOCOUNT ON

        DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
        SET  @TableName = ''
        SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

        WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL

        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName = ''
            SET @TableName = 
            (
                SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
                FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                    AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                    AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                            OBJECT_ID(
                                QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                                 ), 'IsMSShipped'
                                   ) = 0
            )

            WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)

            BEGIN
                SET @ColumnName =
                (
                    SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                    FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                        AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                        AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                        AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
                )

                IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL

                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO #Results
                    EXEC
                    (
                        'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                        FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                        ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                    )
                END
            END    
        END

        SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
    END
```

Comment: What change should I make here If I want to search "Admin" as a example?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a stored procedure that can do that
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/c0c57332-8624-48c0-b4c3-5b31fe641c58