# SQL Server database global search - with reference table - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to do global search in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

Means if I search a string it should fetch the records where the text matches (contains).

And one more scenario: for example my search text match with master data (Parent table), in child table it will have only the reference id. In this case how do I find the record(it should find the child table record).

How to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185871/how-to-search-sql-server-database-for-string and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Its working fine. But its only search the text where its matches but I need to get parent-child table as well, for example my search text match with master data (Parent table), in child table it will have only the reference id. In this case how do I find the record(it should find the child table record). How to handle this scenario